# TypeError when trying to submit a transaction

Tags: javascript, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I'm trying to test out a transaction but composer keeps throwing the following error which I don't quite understand:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'parameters' of undefined
```

It appears to be something to do with the `Parameters concept` in the modelling file. I'm just trying to update the parameters concept in the original asset to the new one defined by the transaction:

**transactionProcessing:**

```
/**
 * Create paramter transaction
 * @param {org.spear.gtm.homenode.parameterUpdate} homeNodeTransaction
 * @transaction
 */
 async function parameterProcessor(homeNodeTransaction){
     const oldParameters = homeNodeTransaction.asset.parameters;
     const newParameters = homeNodeTransaction.newParameters;

     homeNodeTransaction.asset.parameters = homeNodeTransaction.newParameters;
     await getAssetRegistry('org.spear.gtm.homenode').then(registryResults.update(homeNodeTransaction.asset));
     let event = getFactory().newEvent('org.spear.gtm.homenode', 'parameterUpdated');

     event.updatedParameters = newParameters;
     event.oldParameters = oldParameters;

     emit(event);
 }
```

**participant**

```
/*
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

/**
 * The home node is acting as a participant
 */

namespace org.spear.gtm.homenode
import org.spear.gtm.devicenode.IoTDevice
/**
 * Defining participants on the home network
 */

participant HomeNode identified by participantKey {
  //Home node key
  o String participantKey regex = /[A-Fa-f0-9]{64}/

  //parameter concept acts as a parameter dictionary //'old value in transaction Processor'
  o Parameters parameters 

  //reputation paramter
  o Double reputation

  //An array of devices belong to this home node
  --> Devices[] devices
}

concept Parameters {
  //Arbitary string representing JSON parameters
  o String parameters default = 'off'
  /** 
  More parameters to be added
  o Double..
  o Double..
  o Integer..
  */
}

transaction parameterUpdate {
   o Parameters newParameters //'new value in transaction processor'
 }


 transaction addDevice {
   --> IoTDevice device
 }

 event parameterUpdated {
   o Parameters oldParameters
   o Parameters updatedParameters
 }

 event deviceAdded{
   o String homeID
   o String deviceID
 }
```

Comment: The error says `asset` does not exist inside `homeNodeTransaction `

Comment: @KevinAmiranoff ahhh ok thank you